# jquery second callback

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
function callback(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        $('.elements').empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            createElements(results[i]);
        }
    }
}

function createElements(place) {
    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
    var name = place.name;

    $('.elements').after('<p>Name: ' + name + '</p>');
}
```

but when I call callback second time - it appends data, not clear previous list. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('.elements').after('<p>Name: ' + name + '</p>');`

inserts the elements after the selector `$('.elements')` not as a child change to

`$('.elements').append('<p>Name: ' + name + '</p>');`

since `.empty()` will clear the children of the element not siblings

Answer (score 2):

You are not putting your elements inside `.elements`.

Try this:

```
function callback(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        $('.elements').empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            createElements(results[i]);
        }
    }
}

function createElements(place) {
    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
    var name = place.name;

    $('.elements').append('<p>Name: ' + name + '</p>');
}
```